# Determine whether app has been previously installed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I'm about to implement some unlock-functionality In-App-Purchase in an app. The client would like the functionality to be available the first two weeks after installing the app, and then go away until the user pays up.

I need the app to determine whether it has been previously installed, deleted, and installed again. If I can't do that users can just reinstall the app and get two more weeks for free.

Any ideas?

It seems all data is deleted when the app itself is deleted, which kind of limits my options. There is a server backend to the app. Is my best option to log something there or is there another way?

Comment: Your only choice for total control is doing it on the server.  The user can reinstall their OS at any time, making any attempt to do it on the client side futile...

Comment: as u have server back end for the app, you can maintain it their, for first install send the uid of the device to ur server & maintain date, usages anything which u like..

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the keychain in iOS. It will not be removed even if you uninstall the app. But you have to make sure you use the same provisioning profile across different versions of your application.

And, have a look at this [utility](https://github.com/ldandersen/STUtils/blob/master/Security/STKeychain.h)

Comment: It will be removed if the user reinstalls iOS though.

Comment: Yes, if the OS itself is reinstalled, the keychain data will be lost. If that matters, then no other choice, you have to maintain that in server backend.